# Notepad ++: how to paste 50 times for a gallery I'm building

Tags: script, notepad++, html

I'm building a new portofolio page along with some other html based projects. Really heavy on imnage galleries

I export out of lightroom so that each file would be "ADA-#.jpeg" Then I need to add the relevant code to add the photo to the online portofolio and it's match thumbnail.

Is there a plugin or way that I can quickly take a line like this:

```
<img src="gallery/4c/ada-1.jpg" alt="Caption Text"/>
```

Have it Paste 50 times like this automatically:

```
<img src="gallery/4c/ada-2.jpg" alt="Caption Text"/>
<img src="gallery/4c/ada-3.jpg" alt="Caption Text"/>
<img src="gallery/4c/ada-4.jpg" alt="Caption Text"/>
```

....

until it hits 50?

MY php/python skills are really rusty, how about is the actual html to be repeated looks like this:

Event Work

I could figure it out, but I'm super busy >.<

Comment: I always use excel or a google spreadsheet to generate stuff like this...

Comment: Only thing where Sublime Text has an edge over NP++. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use PHP when I need to do things like this because it is easy to script in. I'll write the code for you to do this as an example.

`http://24.3.3.167/test.php` (Test the script here)

```
<?php
   $currentCount = 1;
   while ($currentCount < 51):
      echo htmlspecialchars('<img src=\"gallery/4c/ada-') . $currentCount . htmlspecialchars('.jpg\" alt=\"Caption Text\"/>') . '<br />';
      $currentCount++;
      endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply make a simple javascript function that outputs all the lines for you, having a loop to control the times you need it.

You could make the javascript "paste" the content directly on your html (inside a `<div>` or another tag you need.

Here's an example:

in your html, you may have a div like

```
<div id="myimages"><div/>
```

and have a javascript function (and its call) like:

```
function images(n){
    i=1;
    while(i<=n){
        d = document.getElementById("myimages");
        d.innerHTML  = d.innerHTML+'<img src="gallery/4c/ada-'+i+'.jpg" alt="Caption Text'+i+'"/>\n<br>';
        i++;
    }
}

images(50);
```

then your output will "magically" have all your images =)

[click here for a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bDy2X/)

I recommend you to learn a bit of javascript, or even a server scripting language like PHP, which allows you to make such things without having to write/code repetitive lines like this case.

Answer (score 1):

You may select columns using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>drag</kbd>.

Select the column to be inserted.

[image]

Now go to the file you need to insert to and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>drag</kbd> to select the column

[image]
and then paste the copied column.
And the result you get is...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using `Perl` one line:

```
$ perl -e 'printf "<img src=\"gallery\/4c\/ada-\%d.jpg\" alt=\"Caption Text\"\/>\n", $_ for 1..50'
```

`-e`: Allows you to define Perl code to be executed by the compiler.